# How to setup coinbase wallets for users of my app?

Tags: bitcoin, coinbase-api

I would like to have users sign up for my app with email address, and be given a coinbase wallet with as little friction as possible.

I would then like to send them some coins to get them started.

Is this even possible?

Comment: You don't.  What good would this be if they have no control of the wallet?

Comment: Going along with what @Ramhound said.. why would a user want you to have full access to their wallet? The fact that you asked if it was possible means that you don't fully understand the repercussions of being the creator. You hold the keys to the castle.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it does not appear to be a programming question.

Comment: this is a programming question, i am asking how to use an api to help my users setup a wallet. My users have never used bitcoin before, so i want to reduce friction for them in setting up a wallet. I was hoping u might suggest coinkite or coinbase which allows you to send bitcoin to someone via email which them promts them to set up a wallet, apparently i didn't make my self clear enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this easily with [send money endpoint](https://developers.coinbase.com/api#send-money). If you send funds to an email which isn't signed up, the email address will receive an email notifying to sign up to redeem funds. If the funds haven't been redeemed (i.e. user signed up) in 30 days, the funds will be returned to sender's Coinbase account.